# Convert from FileStream to OutputStream?

Tags: vala

I have a FileStream (GLib.stdout really) and I want to pass it to a function that needs an OutputStream (Vte.Terminal.write_contents). How do you convert between them?

Comment: You can use a `MemoryOutputStream` to dump the results to a `uint8[]`.

Comment: Also you could derive your own `OutputStream`  that writes directly to a `FileStream`, all you have to do is implement `write`, `close` and `flush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new [`UnixOutputStream`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-unix-2.0/GLib.UnixOutputStream.UnixOutputStream) using the file descriptor from the stream you want. (*e.g.*, `new UnixOutputStream(stdout.fileno(), false`)

Comment: Curious that `UnixOutputStream` is not listed as a "known sub-class" here: http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.OutputStream

Comment: Also it doesn't have an object hierarchy diagram.